# What does this line of C code mean?

Tags: c++, c, delphi

I'm converting some C code to Delphi. Can someone please explain to me what this line means?

```
nResult = ( (pBuffer[ 0 ] << 8) & 0xFF00 )
 | ( pBuffer[ 1 ] & 0x00FF );
```

Here is the rest of the code for context:

```
USHORT UTIL_htons( USHORT hostshort )
{
 PUCHAR pBuffer;
 USHORT nResult;

 nResult = 0;
 pBuffer = (PUCHAR )&hostshort;

 nResult = ( (pBuffer[ 0 ] << 8) & 0xFF00 )
  | ( pBuffer[ 1 ] & 0x00FF );

 return( nResult );
}

USHORT UTIL_ntohs( USHORT netshort )
{
 return( UTIL_htons( netshort ) );
}
ULONG UTIL_htonl( ULONG hostlong )
{
 PUCHAR pBuffer;
 ULONG nResult;
 UCHAR c, *pResult;

 pBuffer = (PUCHAR )&hostlong;

 if( !pBuffer )
 {
  return( 0L );
 }

 pResult = (UCHAR * )&nResult;

 c = ((UCHAR * )pBuffer)[ 0 ];
 ((UCHAR * )pResult)[ 0 ] = ((UCHAR * )pBuffer)[ 3 ];
 ((UCHAR * )pResult)[ 3 ] = c;

 c = ((UCHAR * )pBuffer)[ 1 ];
 ((UCHAR * )pResult)[ 1 ] = ((UCHAR * )pBuffer)[ 2 ];
 ((UCHAR * )pResult)[ 2 ] = c;

 return( nResult );
}
ULONG UTIL_ntohl( ULONG netlong )
{
 return( UTIL_htonl( netlong ) );
}
```

Thanks in advance
Bojan

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you stuck on? We like helping people who help themselves, not just do their work for them.

Comment: Ok. To rephrase the question. Can someone explain me the meaning of this line  nResult = ( (pBuffer[ 0 ] << 8) & 0xFF00 )
  | ( pBuffer[ 1 ] & 0x00FF );

Comment: I thick quoted line is self explaining. it gets 8 bits from one buffer element, then 8 bits from another, then concatenates them togeter.

Comment: It's only self-explanatory if you know how to read C, @Vovanium. That means knowing the format for hexadecimal numbers, and knowing the meanings of several operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently (all those defines in uppercase make it hard reading) the functions are swapping the internal byte ordering of values that occupy 2 or 4 bytes. For example:

```
UTIL_htons(0x1234); /* returns 0x3412 */
UTIL_htonl(0x12345678); /* returns 0x78563412 */
```

I have no idea how to write them in Delphi ...

Hopefully they are already written and the library Delphi uses has them with some name or other. Check your documentation.

---

Edit

```
nResult = ( (pBuffer[ 0 ] << 8) & 0xFF00 ) | ( pBuffer[ 1 ] & 0x00FF );
```

in this line

`pBuffer[0]` is the first element of the array `pBuffer`
`pBuffer[0] << 8` is shifting that value 8 bits to the left (0x12 becomes 0x1200)
`(...) & 0xFF00` is redundant: it resets the rightmost 8 bits

In `pBuffer[1] & 0x00FF` only the rightmost 8 bits are kept (so 0x1234 becomes 0x0034)

The other operation `|` is a bitwise or

`( ... & 0xFF00) | ( ... & 0xFF00)` is the leftmost 8 bits of the first part and the rightmost 8 bits of the second part.

---

Edit: hto* / *toh naming

The functions `htonl`, `htons`, `ntohl`, `ntohs` in C are used to convert values between host and network byte order.

The byte ordering is not necessarily different (network byte order is big-endian), so the first part of the functions should check if the host byte ordering is little- or big-endian before doing the swaps ... or the check was done previously in the program that uses the functions you posted.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. In debugging c code and delphi code I made have some similar results: for example nIPOffset = UTIL_ntohs(64) using VC debugger shows value 16384. Same result I have in delphi using ntohs(64). But printf("nIPOffset %d\n", nIPOffset); shows 20.

Comment: nIPOffset = UTIL_ntohs(ip->ip_off); //debugger shows 16384 same is delphi result
printf("nIPOffset %d\n", nIPOffset); //on screen result is 20. That is offset when I have to read new data. Length of data is about 40

Comment: Using "%d" in `printf` tells printf to use an `int` (usually 4 bytes) from the arguments. But nIPOffset appears to be a `long`  or `long long` (8 bytes). If my assumptions are correct `printf` will ignore 4 bytes of the value.

Comment: To print a value of type `long` use `printf("%ld", value);`; for a value of type `long long` use `printf("%lld")`.

Comment: can you explain next please unsigned char ihl: 4, version: 4;

Comment: @bojan: better maybe to ask another question. That's in a `struct` definition, right? It defines struct members `ihl` and `version` both with 4 bits and type `unsigned char`: so their values go from 0 to 15 (making them `unsigned char` is an extension to Standard C)

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to translate them, just include `WinSock`, it has all four of them!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be just a swap of bytes which you can implement very simply:

```
function Swap32(const Value: DWORD): DWORD; assembler;
asm
  bswap eax;
end;

function Swap16(const Value: WORD): WORD; assembler;
asm
  xchg al, ah;
end;
```

Comment: There is awkwardly marked *backward compatibility only* intrinsic `Swap()` procedure for 16 bit byteswap (inlined, save on CALL/RET)            Also, what is const specifier? Do you really want to byteswap **address** of parameter?

Comment: No I don't want to swap the address, the const is just because we don't need to make a copy

Answer (score 0):

rather obscure bitwise expression

```
nResult = ( (pBuffer[ 0 ] << 8) & 0xFF00 )
 | ( pBuffer[ 1 ] & 0x00FF );
```

implies what:

```
var 
  pBuffer: PByteArray; 
  nResult: Word;
```

so, Pascal's structured clarity would look like:

```
WordRec(nResult).Hi := pBuffer^[0];
WordRec(nResult).Lo := pBuffer^[1];
```

even implicit byteswap is being pretty obvious here